# Снижение репутации при одновременной правке

Tags: поддержка, правки

Вчера заметил что от моей репутации отняли 2 очка. Сначала я подумал что меня где-то заминусовали, но проверив статистику не обнаружил ни одного минуса. Так как сняли всего 2 очка (а столько можно получить за правку) то логично было бы предположить, что отменили мою правку. Посмотрев я нашел вопрос, который я правил я обнаружил что его после меня еще кто-то правил. Поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь, но именно из-за этого сняли 2 очка, т.е. как бы отменили мои правки (хотя они остались)? Самое несправедливое, по моему мнению то, что я делал правки по меткам, а другой человек по тексту, но тем не менее очки репутации остаются только у последнего, делавшего правки.

P.S. Для тех кто будет говорить что такое вот поднял из-за каких-то 2-х очков - я просто хочу разобраться в принципе работы SO.

Comment: Только что отредактировал [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425448/) (благо, там было что отредактировать, включая и серьёзную опечатку в коде, допущенную в вашей правке) - ваша репутация как была 951, так и осталась. Более того, за 4 правки в [этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433226) многострадальном вопросе пользователь [Vladimir991](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/29598/vladimir991) получил 8 репутации.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что репутацию, полученную за правку, отнимают, если вопрос был удалён. Это было бы логично.

Comment: Возможно вы правы. Подождем подтверждения от знающих людей. Но  как по мне это не есть честно.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, баллы не отнимают, если пост был отредактирован после Вас. В данном случае я солидарен с @Regent, по поводу удаленного поста. [Здесь](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) расписано, какие действия влияют на репутацию.

Comment: @soon cпасибо за ссылку. Теперь все ясно.